# Proguard and serialization

Tags: java, android

Does pro guard (obfuscation) affect serialization of objects in java. I mean if I use pro guard to obfuscate my code then will serialization still work even if I use serialized object to write it to file and read it again later

Thank you

Comment: See item 19, [Processing serializable classes](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html) in the ProGuard manual.

Comment: If it was an answer i would accept thanks

Comment: Greg's link no longer works now that GuardSquare owns Proguard.  The updated link is [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#serializable).